# How do I display a field that's set to "Hidden" by the content type in the template?

Tags: 6, nodes

I have an existing site where a bunch of the fields are set to **Hidden** in the **Display fields** for the content type. I don't want to change that because I'm not 100% sure how that will affect other aspects of displaying the page.

When I do a var_export($node, TRUE) I can see the field values are present in the node, they just aren't being rendered in $content.

Can I use hook_nodeapi() to change the field display to "Default" or "Trimmed", etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$node->content will be a string containing the generated HTML output of the node's fields that will be displayed.

In hook_nodeapi() the $node->content is already generated, but you can append the hidden field's value to it if needed, with *something* like this:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
    switch($op) {
        case 'view':
            if($node->type == "mytype") {
                $node->content .= "<div>".$node->field_myfield[0]['value']."</div>";
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `field_view_field` function on your node template for your content type:

```
 print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_name'));
```